# How does one delete a project in webstorm.

Tags: ide, webstorm

I have tried the the following https://www.jetbrains.com/webstorm/help/safe-delete.html?search=dele but the safe delete options does not get enabled on the ide.

Answer (score 8):

please try the following:

- in WebStorm, close the project
- delete it from Recent projects list (in Welcome screen, focus the
  project and hit Delete)
- shut down WebStorm
- delete the project folder completely from your disk

Answer (score 0):

To remove project from Webstorm, go to menu and click on File -> Open Recent -> Manage Projects (at the bottom)

In popop which opens highlight the project you want to delete and click on X beside it